# Perl — create numbered backup copy of a file

Tags: perl, file-exists, file-copying

I'm extracting data to some text file but first I want my script to check if file exists, then create copy in a certain folder. If it still exists in the same folder, save it but append like a value _1 or _2 ... depending on the value of the last file.

Here is my script currently,

```
if (-e "/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt"){

    copy("/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt","/tmp/POP") || die "cannot copy file";
    # If the file exists create a copy in /tmp/POP

    #################################
    # IF FILE EXISTS IN /tmp/POP copy the file but rename it to 
    # POP_Airtime_Week1_1.txt then increase the numbers each time
    # the script is run and a new copy needs to be created.
    ##################################

    unlink ("/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt");

}
```

If `/tmp/POP/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt` exists, then copy it but save it as `/tmp/POP/POP_Airtime_Week1_1.txt`. The next time I run the script and `/tmp/POP/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt` exists, copy it and save it as `/tmp/POP/POP_Airtime_Week1_2.txt`  etc...

How can I do this?

Comment: All that's missing is a loop and a counter.

Comment: Why not use an existing tool like logrotate?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "use File::Copy;" in the beginning of the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can increment a variable while the target file exists:

```
my $name = "POP_Airtime_Week1";
if (-e "/tmp/POP/$name.txt") {
    my $num = 1;
    $num ++ while (-e "/tmp/POP/$name\_$num.txt");
    copy("/tmp/$name.txt","/tmp/POP/$name\_$num.txt") or die "cannot copy file";
} else {
    copy("/tmp/$name.txt","/tmp/POP/$name.txt") or die "cannot copy file";
}
```

Be warned, though. If you (or you and someone else) run more than one instance of the script, there is a possibility of race condition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I just thought it was an unfinished name of the file :) Fixed.

Comment: tried that the first time i run it, it creates and copies tp a new file /tmp/POP/POP_Airtime_Week1_1; the next time i run that, /tmp/POP/POP_Airtime_Week1_2 is not created and neither is the previous data written to any other file. However /tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1 is already overwritten.

Comment: @OmbongiMoraa: The script *never* overwrites the original file. It only creates copies in the POP subdirectory.

Comment: sorry, forgot to say i included unlink ("/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt"); line as in my question. This allows for the /tmp copy of the file to be deleted coz I wanted for /tmp/POP to handle old copies. if i dont unlink the /tmp file then I'll get the error that it exists and my script terminates prematurely.

Comment: @OmbongiMoraa: Works for me. What error do you get if the file exists? Have you created the `/tmp/POP` directory?

Comment: yes i have /tmp/POP directory and on the first run, PEP_Airtime_Week1_1.txt was added to it. However on subsequent runs, no additional files are created. if file exists (THAT IS I DONT UNLINK) i get         DBD::mysql::st execute failed: File '/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt' already exists at /home/faith/allScriptsToStudy_FAITH/POPAirtime.pl line 38.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: File '/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt' already exists at /home/faith/allScriptsToStudy_FAITH/POPAirtime.pl line 38.
Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of DBD::mysql::db handle ...

Comment: @OmbongiMoraa: Which line is line 38?

Comment: line 38 is the $sth->execute(); statement after my select that loads data infile "/tmp/POP_Airtime_Week1.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
 my $i = 0;
 my $fname = $file;
 for (;;) {
     last unless -f $fname;
     $i++;
     $fname = "${file}_$i";
 }
 # $fname is new unused file name, copy to it
```